# How to consume SOAP web services in Jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, web-services, soap, jquery-mobile

How to consume SOAP web services in Jquery mobile? My web service is been made in ASP.NET. I want to consume it using Jquery mobile. Sorry but I don't know anything about service integration and stuff so I want you guys to tell me from scratch how this process begins.
I do know about how SOAP service works, I use SOAPUI to pass the data and get a response in XML page...
What I need is how to invoke it using jquery, how to pass the data in web service methods and as the response comes in XML, how to convert it and put it in my HTML page to display...

Please tell me everything from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you'll need to find out the exact structure of the SOAP request and build it in javascript, you can see an example [here](http://openlandscape.net/2009/09/25/call-soap-xm-web-services-with-jquery-ajax/).

But to make things easier, i'd suggest you write a simple .NET class that accepts simple http requests, and let it handle the actual SOAP request.

So from your code you'll call that simple class with simple AJAX call, that class will call the SOAP web service and then return the answer, preferably in a JSON format.